# Why isn't the set $\{\;f\in\Bbb{R}[x]\mid f=0 \;\text{or}\; \deg(f)=2\;\}$, with operation $+$, a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Why isn't the set $\{\;f\in\Bbb{R}[x]\mid f=0 \;\text{or}\; \deg(f)=2\;\}$, with operation $+$, a group?

I thinking that if you add two polynomials, like $ f(x) = 3x^{2}$ and $g(x) = 2x^{2}$ you get $5x^{2}$, but they said it is false and the zero-polynomial is an inverse. I don't understand why they say it is false. And every element has an inverse including the zero polynomial?

Comment: Hint: the set is not closed under addition.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that $ax^2+bx+c$ is also of degree 2. (for $a\neq0$)

Comment: It's not false that $3x^2+2x^2=5x^2$, but that doesn't mean the set is closed under addition, to see that it isn't, consider what happens if the terms of highest degree cancel each other out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x) = x^2 + x$ and $g(x) = -x^2$. Are $f,g$ in your set? Is $f+g$?

Comment: but can you really count in x^(2)+x as a polynom as degree 2?

Comment: What degree should it have in your opinion? It seems you are thinking of **monomials**, terms of the form $ax^k$ with $a$ being a coefficient (real in that case) and $k \in \mathbb Z, k \ge 0$. If you only consider monomials with $k=2$, then you are right, they form a group, isomorphic to to $(\mathbb R,+)$. But that is not what people understand as polynomials of degree $2$, which **does** contain $x^2+x$. Notice the naming scheme, **polyonomials** contain sums of **monomials**.